# How do i direct a custom subdomain to a specific html page in firebase hosting?

Tags: html, hosting, firebase-hosting

I've tried setting the domain registrar's DNS

I did something like this;

subdomain.customdomain.com | type:cname | subdomain.firebaseapp.com

Comment: Hosting multiple subdomains on different Firebase projects is not yet supported in Firebase Hosting. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30147602/how-do-i-make-a-custom-subdomain-on-firebase, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168120/use-apex-domain-and-subdomain-for-different-firebase-projects

Comment: i just need 1 custom subdomain for a specific html page and the rest can be accessed without the subdomain. all of these are in the same firebase project

Comment: It doesn't matter whether it's only for a single HTML page: hosting multiple subdomains on different Firebase projects is not yet supported in Firebase Hosting.